# Windows 8 - placing the header of GridView in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8

I have a GridView:

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="400" Header="AAAAAA">
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        </GridView>
```

[image]

I simply want that AAAAA on the upper side on the GridView, not the left where it intervene position of my GridViewItem. You know, like in Music apps on Windows 8, the title "now playing >" or "most popular >" are placed in the upper side of the GridView. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```xaml
    <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="400" Header="AAAAA">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
    </GridView>
```

Alternatively, instead of using GridView's Header, you could do something like this:

```xaml
    <Grid Width="400" Height="300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" Text="My Header" Margin="0 20" />
        <GridView Grid.Row="1">
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: your alternative is genius! it leaves my context of having a header but creating a TextBlock duplicate which does the exact thing I wish. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="400">
        <GridView.Header> <TextBlock Text="AAAAA" Margin="240,0,0,0"/>
        </GridView.Header>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
    </GridView>
```

You can set whatever property you want for the TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="400" Header="AAAAA">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-80,20,0,0" Width="400" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
    </GridView>

Or you can adjust the margin of the variableSizedWrapGrid, so that the alignment of the header and Items should appear in same line
```

Answer (score 0):

<--Try this-->

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Grid.Row="1" Height="400">
<GridView.Header>
<TextBlock Text="AAAAA" />
</GridView.Header>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="-35,20,0,0"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
<GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" Margin="0"/>
</GridView>
```